# Rickroll dupes again: is "First they came" a dupe?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, duplicates

[First they came](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/139900/58826) has been dupe-hammered of [We're no strangers to code golf, you know the rules, and so do I](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/6043/58826) (the rickroll), and reopened within 14 minutes.

The question is: Is it a dupe?

### Note that voting on this question *does not* signify your opinion on the dup status. Please vote on answers.

Comment: Although I think this meta question is a duplicate, I'd like to see more answers on the original meta question, as it doesn't seem clear that kolmogorov complexity questions should be considered duplicates just because some of the same techniques can be used. Otherwise we'd be closing golf and fastest code challenges for being solvable using golfing techniques and optimisation techniques.

Comment: @trichoplax, a more accurate analogy would be closing https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/101240/194 as a duplicate of the Fibonacci question. (For the avoidance of doubt: it *is* closed as a duplicate of the Fibonacci question, and quite correctly, because it *uses the same technique* in the sense that the code is identical apart from, depending on implementation, one or two constants).

Answer (score 3):

## No

Please, stop closing [kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity) as dupes of the rickroll, especially small output ones like this. It is hard to make answers from one competitive in the other, and therefore is not a dupe.

Comment: Beyond that though... We don't want 102041950195 of these a week.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn We don't get that many though, shouldn't we address a problem only when it happens?

Comment: @LiefdeWen meh, I'd say only VTC non-interesting ones, but it's entirely subjective as to what constitutes an non-interesting duplicate.

Comment: "*It is hard to make answers from one competitive in the other*" is factually inaccurate. It is depressingly easy, and it frustrates me that some people seem to wilfully refuse to take that on board.

Comment: @PeterTaylor the ease or difficulty of a task is only determined by the skill and knowledge of the person taking on the challenge, what is easy for you isn't necessarily easy for me.

Comment: @Notts90, in context there is an obvious prerequisite. *If* you can write a competitive answer to the rickroll question, you can easily adapt it to any other structured song, and vice versa. And if you can't write a competitive answer to either, you don't really lose much by only having one of the two being open.

Comment: PS For what it's worth, I've *automated* it and posted the program on Github at the request of another PPCG user. I actually lose the potential to gain rep by FGITWing song threads, but I consider that promoting consistent implementation of the site policy on duplicates is more important than my own rep score.